# Spring Boot JSON Serialization

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and created a REST controller to add a JSON object into Mongo DB collections.

The data to be added from the JSON object will be a subset of information received from the request. So i have created a JSON request object ( DTO ) and an entity object ( model ) to be stored in Mongo collection.

I'm facing an issue now as the JSON request object is populated with default values for integer ( 0 ) and boolean data types ( false ) even if these fields are not populated as part of the request message.  I don't want to store these values in the database.

I have added " spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non-null " and " spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non-default "  properties in my application.properties file but still the fields are populated with default values.
Could anyone please help me out in resolving this issue and bypass the default values. NOTE: It works fine for String data type as they would be NULL values by default if not created.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi All,The issue is now resolved by changing the primitive data types to their corresponding Wrapper Classes. ( Ex: from boolean to Boolean , int to Integer ).

Answer (score 2):

String Attributes accept the null value while the primitive attributes have a default value for example 0 is default value for the int attributes.. to avoid having this values Use **Integer** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this annotation above your fields in bean class with which you facing the problem and tell me your problem is solved.

'@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)'

Thanks